# Is there a way to "lazy load" images in a tab?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to display in some cases upwards of 250 images in a scrollable tab on a web page. The thing that scares me about doing this is the possible lag in UI responsiveness due to so many images getting loaded all at once.

Is there a way to prevent displaying of images until they are scrolled into view so that only the small percentage of them that are displayed at any given time (4 or 5 on a phone, maybe 40 or so on a large desktop) are loaded (just-in-time)?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of plug-ins that allow you to do so.

Comment: You can also do it yourself $.post() calls and onscroll events and detecting the window location, but the plugins are likely the better bet.

Comment: Any recommendations on which plugin is best for this? Or something *you* have used that works? In my previous site, I first used lightbox, but that was a waste of time, as I eventually found that fancybox was much better.